# Como hacer para que un Objecto DTO de java me muestre un registro en una ventana p:dialog de primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Tengo el siguiente problema, Realice un Objeto DTO para visualizar datos en una tabla, y esto lo hace bien, el problema surge porque hay un campo donde trae mucho texto y la verdad es impresentable, entonce hice una logica usando JAVA y Primefaces para que solo me mostrara 500 caracteres y si se exedia me mostrara 500 caracteres y un boton, ese boton me abre una ventana de dialogo y dentro de ella le paso el valor que quiero mostrar, el proble es que la informacion que me sale en este cuadro de dialogo es correspondiente al ultimo registro y no al registro que se selecciona.

por aca dejo micodigo de Java y Prime Primefaces

// Codigo para mostrar caracteres

```
public String getSolutionAdvance() {
    int caracteres = solutionAdvance.length();
    
    if(caracteres > 500){
        return solutionAdvance.substring(0, 499);
    }else{        
        return solutionAdvance;
    }
}
```

// Codigo para mostrar el boton (valuebutton por defecto es false)

```
public boolean getValuebutton() {
    // Muestra el boton solo si supera los 500 caracteres
    int caracteres = solutionAdvance.length();
    
    if(caracteres > 500){
        valuebutton = true;
        return valuebutton;
    }else{        
        return valuebutton;
    }
}
```

// Codigo Primefaces

```
<p:column headerText="Solucion y/o Avance">
    <h:outputText value="#{service.solutionAdvance}"/>
    <br/>
    <p:commandButton value="Ver mas" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" rendered="#{service.valuebutton}"/> 
                        
    <p:dialog header="Solucion / Avances o Notas de Trabajo" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="bounce" height="100">
        <h:outputText value="#{service.solutionAdvance}"/>
    </p:dialog>                            
</p:column>
```

La Cuestion aca es como hacer para que aparesca en ese cuadro el registro que se selecciona y no el ultimo.